# iPhone Screenshots Pixelated

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup, skew

I am having a problem putting screenshots into the iPhone image. As you see, the screenshot is pixelated. Do you know how to make clear screenshot? Basically I am using skew tool to fit the screenshot into the image. Please Let me know if you guys know about the solution! thanks[image]

Comment: Was the screenshot pixelated before you inserted it? My guess is no. So your question should really be, why did my screenshot become pixelated after I skewed it (if that is the case).

Comment: You have to use the smart object that came with the stock image you have. If you double click in it, it will open in another tab, and there you can put your screenshot. When you click save, it will automatically change in the stock image as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Double-klick** the layer named "DoubleClick" and place your screenshot there instead of skewing it yourself.

From the file description at GraphicBurger:

> The PSD files include smart objects so you can easily obtain a neat,
>   photorealistic presentation.